# Linking custom HTML Form to Google Form (How to handle Date input?)

Tags: html, forms, google-forms

I am trying to link a custom HTMl form to an existing Google Form. I have matched the  action and  name attributes to the form (placeholders in html snippet below for privacy).

My custom Form

```
<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/PLACEHOLDERurl" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="mb-0" for="name">First & Last Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="entry.PLACEHOLDER" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="date" class="mb-0">Pick Up Date</label>
    <input id="pick-up-date" type="date" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <button id="testFormSubmit" type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-main-color">Submit</button>
</form>
```

However, there are 3 "name" attributes for the date input on the google form.

Main date input from Google Form

```
<input type="date" class="quantumWizTextinputPaperinputInput exportInput" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" value="" data-initial-value="2020-04-14" badinput="false" dir="ltr">
```

3 hidden inputs for each name value (year, day, month) from Google Form

```
<input type="hidden" name="entry.2099319546_year" jsname="L9xHkb_year" value="2020">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.2099319546_month" jsname="L9xHkb_month" value="4">
<input type="hidden" name="entry.2099319546_day" jsname="L9xHkb_day" value="14">
```

Can someone please let me know how I can alter my custom date form input to match this format?

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with same problem but turns out the solution is pretty easy.
You just need to delete the underscore value ('_year') and use only the entry id.

```
entry.2099319546
```

Doesn't matter that they have three different inputs and you only have one, Google will recognize it no matter way.

[Check this tutorial from Codepen](https://codepen.io/learningcode/post/customize-a-google-form-for-your-website)